# How do I make my react-bootstrap-table column size responsive based on the size of the content in the table?

Tags: reactjs

How do I make it so that there is less space 'wasted' in each cell? And when the content changes in size, the header and cell size will accommodate that change?

PS. only address has that overflow feature

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can use **tdStyle**.

```
<TableHeaderColumn 
  dataField='column1'
  width="50" 
  <--!set a fixed column width to reduce col width if needed -->
  tdStyle={{ whiteSpace: 'normal', wordWrap: 'break-word' }} 
  <--!wrap word instead of elipsis -->
>
    Column Name
</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: it does make it wrap around and break the word but I want it to get longer or shorter based on the content, is it possible for me to do that?

Comment: I don't think react-bootstrap-table makes this out of the box. A workaround is that you can calculate the length of text in each column, then set the width property to a percentage value, such as 10%, 20%.